# How to pick up a call by adb

Tags: android, service, android-intent, adb

Can I pick up a call by any adb command? I know that you can dial a number by "adb shell service call phone 2 s16 "+15084157509".

Can phone service do pick-up call or can I send some adb command to manipulate activity?

much appreciated

Comment: Related: [How to make a call via pc by ADB command on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4923550/3258851); [How can incoming calls be answered programmatically in Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26924618/3258851)

Answer (score 6):

adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_CALL

Answer (score 4):

To call `TelephonyManager.answerRingingCall()` use `adb shell service call phone 5` command.

Comment: Fantastic!!! What about hitting a button in that call would it be as previously stated?

Comment: Also would this require root access if I was using tasker?

Comment: @RobertJ yes this requires root access.

Answer (score 2):

That works for me:

```
 adb shell input keyevent 5
```

Answer (score -2):

Set the following property on far end to auto answer the incoming call in 2 seconds

```
adb shell setprop persist.sys.tel.autoanswer.ms 2000
```

To turn off auto answer,

```
adb shell setprop persist.sys.tel.autoanswer.ms 0
```

Answer (score -3):

adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:555-5555

Comment: this is dailing a number. but is there any way to pick up an incoming call?

Comment: i don't think that such a command-line exist whith adb you can simulate a call only with adb

Comment: awesome, found a solution, adb shell input keyevent 5

Comment: @JimmyWu you should post your solution as an answer and resolve this question.