# Lollipop : Accept incoming call Programatically in android lollipop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I'm using the below code to answer an incoming call from my app(BroadcastReceiver's `onReceive()`) , it is working in **Kitkat** . The same code is not working in **Lollipop**.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
// send ordered broadcast
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
```

Please let me know how can I answer a call in **Lollipop**.

Thank you.

Comment: Follow this link. Answer no 2
I have tested and its working
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop

Comment: are you able to reject the call Also .. ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.Put this code in your broadcast reciever for action "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" .Your phone needs to be rooted.Generate an apk file of ur app and put it into /system/priv-apps/ .Works for Android v 5.0 i.e lollipop.

```
   final String LOG_TAG = "TelephonyAnswer";

    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try {
        if (tm == null) {
            // this will be easier for debugging later on
            throw new NullPointerException("tm == null");
        }
        // do reflection magic
        tm.getClass().getMethod("answerRingingCall").invoke(tm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Do not forget to add permission in ur manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

if modify_phone_state doesnt work explicitly ask for one by using this code

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE},
                1);
```

and overide method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            } else {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied to pick call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Lollipop, if our application is `System app or application has root access` then only we can programmatically answer incoming call

> For 3rd party developer application, Lollipop OS do not allow to
>   answer programmatically to incoming call

You can check if how to do it for system app or with root access : [In this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27084305/1994950)

Comment: welcome.. Is you application 3rd party or system or having root access application? Is this answer solved your problem?

Comment: no the prob is not solved.. as it is a 3rd party app.