# Android: howto pick up automatically when a certain number calls?

Tags: java, android

I want to create a program for Android which picks up automatically when a certain number calls and answer with dtmf tone. Is this possible in Android Java?

Comment: You can use Random class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanted to be aware that a certain number had called and then do some non call action, such as log the call, send a notification to a server etc then you can simply use the Android TelephonyManager () and create a BroadcastReceiver to listen for incoming call events. There are quite a few examples of how to use it to detect incoming calls available with a quick search.

If you want to actually answer the call then strictly speaking in 'standard' Android terms you can't. However, take a look at this excellent answer (not mine...) for some workarounds which may possibly work for you depending on your particular solution (whether your target devices are rooted etc):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27084305/334402