# Can't auto answer phone call within my Android System App via ITelephony

Tags: android, root, android-hardware

I would like to make use of android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE on Android Lollipop by auto-answering a call, much like some of the hands-free "driver assist" apps that are available on the Play Store.

I found some code from the [AutoAnswer project](https://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer/AutoAnswerIntentService.java), but when I run it, I get a InvocationTargetException stating that "neither the user #### nor the application has MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permissions."

However, in my Manifest I have: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />` and I have installed my apk into `/system/app/AutoAnswer.apk` and set it's permissions to 644.

The requirement is that I don't need a phone to be rooted in order for it to work, but I do have the ability to add my application to the custom ROM (so it is a system app).

The calling code looks like this:

```
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        Object telephonyService = m.invoke(tm);

        Method m1 = telephonyService.getClass().getMethod("silenceRinger");
        Method m2 = telephonyService.getClass().getMethod("answerRingingCall");

        //m1.invoke(telephonyService); // not supported for OnePlus2
        m2.invoke(telephonyService); // <- This is the line that throws the error
```

Why is it not allowing me to use MODIFY_PHONE_STATE from my system app..? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Does it signed by same signature, which was used to sign your ROM? Both  should be signed by same. Pushing apk into /system/ is not enaugh to make application as system app.

Comment: No it wasn't signed using the same signature. MODIFY_PHONE_STATE is marked as "signatureOrSystem" so I read this as either signed by the same signature OR is run from a system app..? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f4ece2086f3b7060edc4b93a12f04c9af648867a%5E!/

Answer (score 1):

For a work around you may wish to check out [How can incoming calls be answered programmatically in Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop)

If getting explicit grant of Notification access from the user is ok then you can check out my answer there which worked for me under Android 5.0 and 5.1.