# How to answer a call programmatically

Tags: android, phone-call, telephony, telephonymanager

How to answer a call programatically.

I have tried to implement the below code using `TelephonyManager`.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if (tm == null) {
    // whether you want to handle this is up to you really
    throw new NullPointerException("tm == null");
}
tm.answerRingingCall();
```

But, It is not working. Is there any other ways to do the same.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565820/android-call-answering-programatically

Comment: This guy has explained beautifully-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop