# Is there anyway to pick up the incoming call Automatically in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, android-developer-api

I am developing a project in which I want to pick up the incoming call automatically after the certain interval, play an audio file and record the conversation for minute.
As I have been Successful in implementing **Callreciever Function** in which I can able to detect the current call state of my phone.

CallReciever.Java

```
package com.example.deepdepindersingh.activevoice;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by Deep Depinder Singh on 8/21/2016.
 */
public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

    @Override

    // call comming
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {

        Toast.makeText(ctx, number , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override

    //Call picked by me
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, number , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    // Call ended by me
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, number , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, number , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can incoming calls be answered programmatically in Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop)

Comment: I dont want to answer incoming call just want to pick up after certain interval

Comment: I have read this link u have posted, but not found helpful

Comment: did you try this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27084305/3678308 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually autoanswering and yes there is way to pick up call automatically in android ,for that you must use these code available at [autoanswer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/auto-answer/) . I think it will help you , it is a complete tutorial for your task.

Comment: How to download this link

Comment: just go here https://code.google.com/archive/p/auto-answer/source/default/source  and click on download

Comment: I will try...to implement this