# Answer call programatically in Android Marshmallow 6.0

Tags: android

Want to have the app answer a call without any user intervention.

I have this working in Lollipop based on this post :

[How can incoming calls be answered programmatically in Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop)

But it isn't working on a 6.0 device.

Does anyone have a solution that is working for Marshmallow?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you might have forgotten the permissions. You have to ask for them at runtime in Android 6+. Just to test it you can go to settings in your phone and find your app and allow the setting manually to test it.

Comment: I am targeting 5.0 when building so permissions still handled at install time even when running on 6.0. thx.