# Wrong when register two receiver in an activity Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have an activity. It will be receive two variable from an service. In the service, I will send two variable to the activity by

```
 // Send first variable 
 sendBroadcast(new Intent("first_one"));
 // Send second variable 
 sendBroadcast(new Intent("second_one"));
```

Now, In the activity, I used bellow code to receive the data. There are

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        registerReceiver(firstRec, new IntentFilter("first_one"));
        registerReceiver(secondRec, new IntentFilter("second_one"));
    }   
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (firstRec != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(firstRec);
            firstRec = null;
        }
        if (secondRec != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(secondRec);
            secondRec = null;
        }
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver firstRec = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("TAG","OK first");
        }
    };

    private BroadcastReceiver secondRec = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("TAG","OK second");
        }
    };
```

However, I cannot print the log "OK second" when I called sendBroadcast(new Intent("second_one")); in the service. What is happen? How can I fix it? Thank you

UPDATE: my activity is an accept calling activity get from @notz
[How can incoming calls be answered programmatically in Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop). Then I create an service as following

```
public class myService extends Service{
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
 }
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
   return null;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   Intent answerCalintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AcceptCallActivity.class);
   answerCalintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
   answerCalintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(answerCalintent);
   //Send the second command after 10 second and make the calling in background
   new CountDownTimer(10000, 100) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
        public void onFinish() {
           sendBroadcast(new Intent("second_one"));
        }
   }.start();

   return START_STICKY;
}
}
```

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: registerReceiver in onResume and check.

Comment: variable means broadcast i guess

Comment: @Ready Android how it will help him

Comment: @user8264 can you please send code where you sending broadcast

Comment: @Jitesh I didn't get "how it will helo me" ?. Actually broadcast receiver register and unregister have life cycle. If you are unregistering a broadcast in onPause then it should be registered in onResume, generally.

Comment: @KostasDrak: I have no error. Just does not print the log when I call the function to send the second command

Comment: @ReadyAndroid: If I register in onResume, could I need to register it in onCreate(); I registered it onResume but it has same issue

Comment: @user8264: From where you are calling `sendBroadcast` ?

Comment: In an service, just send a command from my service to activity.

Comment: @user8264: k, just send second and check getting string in log or not

Comment: Right. I just call only sendBroadcast(new Intent("second_one")); in my service but the log in the activity does not show

Comment: @user8264: Activity is running or not?

Comment: Yes, it is running in background before.

Comment: @user8264: That's why not showing messages in Logs. try it after opening Activity then check it

Comment: @user8264 please mention your code service code where you are sending broadcast

Comment: The activity is an accept call activity of @notz in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop

Comment: @all: Thanks all. I updated my full code. Let see it. Note that, after calling the calling activity. I will press the home button to make the activity is running in background

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. It is because onPause function is called when I press the home, although the calling phone is still running. Thus, I changed the onPause to onDestroy. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should unregister your reсeiver in a method opposite to that in which you register it:
If you registered receiver in onCreate() - then you should unregister it in onDestroy().
But as i know, for most cases, the best practice is to register receiver in onResume() and unregister it in onPause().