# Answer phone calls programmatically in Android Wear (version 5.1)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, wear-os

I am developing an App for Android wear(Android version 5.1). In which I want to answer calls programmatically. I found lot of posts online which use:

```
 try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " +
                Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Runtime.exec(String) had an I/O problem, try to fall back
        String enforcedPerm = "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED";
        Intent btnDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
        Intent btnUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

        mContext.sendOrderedBroadcast(btnDown, enforcedPerm);
        mContext.sendOrderedBroadcast(btnUp, enforcedPerm);
    }
```

I got the code from the below link. 
[How can incoming calls be answered programmatically in Android 5.0 (Lollipop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop][1])

I have tried most of these solutions but it does not help in answering the calls in Android wear.

Any help is appreciated.