# Answer phone calls programmatically in Android (version 5.1)

Tags: android, call, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am developing an App for Android(Android version 5.1). In which I want to answer calls programmatically. I found lot of posts online which use:

```
 try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " +
            Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Runtime.exec(String) had an I/O problem, try to fall back
    String enforcedPerm = "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED";
    Intent btnDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    Intent btnUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON).putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

    mContext.sendOrderedBroadcast(btnDown, enforcedPerm);
    mContext.sendOrderedBroadcast(btnUp, enforcedPerm);
}
```

But the above code does not seem to work for me. Please can anyone help?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29651130/1507512

Comment: I have tried it before. But it still does not work for me @Massimo