# How to send a keystroke through adb during a phone call?

Tags: android, events, call, adb, dtmf

I would like to be able to use ADB to fully manage the process of a phonecall (primarily as I have cracked my screen and cannot see anything).

I know I can initiated a phonecall through:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:1234567890
```

Similarly I know I can use key events to end a call:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENDCALL
```

However I have run into issues when the voicemail asks "press 1 to listen to your message, 2 for settings, etc".

I was hoping that the following command would work:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_1
```

or at least the following:

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 2 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 2 0
```

However the voicemail does not recognise the selection and just repeats the message. I have no way to validate visually as I have no access to the screen.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help.

*References:*

1. Making a call through adb [How to make a call via pc by ADB command on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923550/how-to-make-a-call-via-pc-by-adb-command-on-android)
2. Input event and events' list [ADB Shell Input Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events)
3. Send event https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-beginners/il2PqSKRFNI

Answer (score 0):

During the call you need to switch to the "Dialpad" tab in order to be able to send the DTMF codes

Comment: That makes perfect sense :) Since I have read your reply I have been looking into how to switch to the Dialpad (within CM10 rom), however I have not had much luck so far. Do you happen to know the command that would be required? I assume that once I have switched to Dialpad one of the two approaches identified in the original post will then work.

Comment: I am stuck in a similar issue, so did you find any resolution for it?