# How to initiate & pick up a video call via pc by ADB command on android?

Tags: android, video, adb, telephony

Can some one tell me how i can initiate & pickup a video call using adb? I want to automate some Video Telephony Testing and want to do this using adb_scripts. Is it possible at all?

I can see the following link in stackoverflow to initiate a voice only call using adb. I just cannot correlate the same to initiate video call.

[How to make a call via pc by ADB command on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923550/how-to-make-a-call-via-pc-by-adb-command-on-android)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

\\ To Initiate the Video call

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx --ei android.telecom.extra.START_CALL_WITH_VIDEO_STATE 3**
```

\\ To auto answer on far end

```
adb shell setprop persist.sys.tel.autoanswer.ms 2000
```

Comment: Thanks Alexan,  `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx --ei android.telecom.extra.START_CALL_WITH_VIDEO_STATE 3` work (not include **)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this for setting up a call:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:+1-xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

This ends a call:

```
adb shell input keyevent 6
```

I have not tried this but it might answer a call:

```
adb shell input keyevent 5
```